# The globally static error (modelsim vs quartus)

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus

This simple test leads to an error while compiling with modelsim whereas Quartus is fine to go through the whole synthesis/fitter process.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity submodule is
port(
  four_bits_input  : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  four_bits_output : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end entity;

architecture behav of submodule is
begin
  four_bits_output <= four_bits_input;
end architecture;

-------------------------------------------------------

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity globally_static_test is
port (
  one_bits_input   : in std_logic;
  three_bits_input : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  four_bits_output : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end entity;

architecture behav of globally_static_test is
begin

submodule_inst : entity work.submodule
port map(
   four_bits_input  => one_bits_input & three_bits_input  -- Modelsim Error is here.
  ,four_bits_output => four_bits_output
);

end architecture;
```

Modelsim error is the well known :

> (vcom-1436) Actual expression (infix expression) of formal
>   "four_bits_input" is not globally static.

I have seen this type of affectation in wrapper a lot in different companies and on several projects.

My question is : "Who is actually right ? Modelsim or Quartus".

***Edit :***

I've first made the test with the following versions

- Modelsim v10.5b Intel FPGA Starter Edition - VHDL 2002
- Quartus Prime 17.1 - VHDL 1993

Then I changed the Modelsim compilation option to use VHDL 2008 and the error is gone.

Comment: "Duplicate" of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244453/does-vhdl-permit-logic-operation-in-port-map (The link is to EE-SE)

Comment: Your question may not have a reproducible error. What VHDL revisions are you using for the two tools (and what versions are they)? In IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3 Port clauses an actual that is a non-static expression elaborates an anonymous signal as the target, used as the actual associated with the formal (which supplies the type and constraint, `four_bits_input has a locally static subtype).

Comment: I edited my post to add the tools and VHDL versions. I think it may be time for me to use VHDL-2008 as default in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have concatenation form in port segment, so define a signal instead, and give the concatenation form to it.

Comment: The use of a non-static actual in a port association was introduced in IEEE Std 1076-2008. See the subsection referenced by user1155120 in the above comment. Note user grorel's follow up comment. Your answer is less than precise, can you clarify with a verfiable answer?